# Rails and MiniTest: add additional folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I use Ruby 2 and Rails 4. I have a folder `test/lib`, where a few tests are located.
But running `rake test` does not use them. Only the other tests (models, controllers, ...) are running.

Where do I have to add the `lib` folder?

I already tried `MiniTest::Rails::Testing.default_tasks << 'lib'`, but I get `NameError Exception: uninitialized constant MiniTest::Rails`. I did not add the minitest gem to my Gemfile, because Ruby 2 uses it by default.

Comment: you can override the task `rake test` in `Rakefile` by creating a new task with executing `ruby -Ilib:test  "test/lib/*"

Comment: The simplest solution for me is to use `rake test:all` instead of `rake test`

Comment: For Rails 4.2 `rake test:all` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5. But `rake test` now works exactly the same.

Answer (score 13):

To use `MiniTest::Rails::Testing.default_tasks << 'lib'` you need to add the [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) gem to your Gemfile. It is separate from Minitest and adds enables many Minitest features missing that are not enabled in Rails by default. And minitest-rails adds other features, such as creating rake tasks for all the directories that have tests. So without any changes to your Rakefile you can run things like this:

```
$ rake minitest:lib
```

Alternatively, to do this the old fashioned way, you can add the following to your Rakefile:

```
namespace :test do

  desc "Test lib source"
  Rake::TestTask.new(:lib) do |t|    
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/lib/**/*_test.rb'
    t.verbose = true    
  end

end

Rake::Task[:test].enhance { Rake::Task["test:lib"].invoke }
```

This assumes you want to run your lib tests without using any database fixtures. If you want the fixtures and database transactions, then you should create the rake task with a dependency on "test:prepare".

```
namespace :test do

  desc "Test lib source"
  Rake::TestTask.new(:lib => "test:prepare") do |t|    
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/lib/**/*_test.rb'
    t.verbose = true    
  end

end

Rake::Task[:test].enhance { Rake::Task["test:lib"].invoke }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think you mean "add the following to your Rakefile", not Gemfile though.

Comment: on rails 4 this adds 3 seconds to boot, just for an empty test/lib dir

Comment: Is this supposed to be Rake::TestTask or Rails::TestTask? First one seems to produce many errors before actually running the tests.